# Sudoku 9 boxes ( 3x3 ) Recursion Backtracking in C all combinations

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote a sudoku for 3x3 ( 9 boxes ) I want to make it recursive and generate all the combinations but I don't know where I went wrong ...
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define dbg 0
using namespace std; 
int n,st[100][100];

void afisare()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
        for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
            printf("%2d",st[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int valid(int k,int ii,int jj)
{
    int i,j;
//  if(k==1){
//      if(dbg)printf("\nReturnez 1 deoarece k-ul este egal cu 1");
//  return 1;
//  }

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
            if((i==ii) && (j==jj))
            {
                if(dbg)
                    printf("\nValorile nu indeplinesc criteriul, se incrementeaza j.");
            }
            else
            {
                if(dbg)
                    printf("\n i= %d j= %d",i,j);

                if(dbg)
                    printf("\nSe verifica daca %d este egal cu casuta %d %d",k,i,j);

                if(k==st[i][j]) {
                    if(dbg)printf("\nValorile sunt egale, returnez 0");
                    return 0;
                }
            }

    if(dbg)
        printf("\nValorile nu sunt egale, deci returnez 1");

    return 1;
} 

void back(int k)
{
    int i,j;

    if(dbg) printf("\nk=",k);

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
            if(dbg)
                printf("\nVerifica daca casuta %d %d este egal cu 0",i,j);

            if(st[i][j]==0) {
                if(dbg) printf("\n Este egal cu 0");
                if(dbg) printf("\n%d ia valoarea %d.",st[i][j],k);

                st[i][j]=k;

                if(dbg)
                    printf("\nSe verifica valabilitatea numarului %d",st[i][j]);

                // while(valid(k,i,j)!=0)
                if(valid(k,i,j)!=0) {
                    valid(++k,i,j);
                    //back(k+1);
                }
                else
                    do {
                        st[i][j]=k+1;
                        if(dbg)
                            printf("\nCasuta %d %d are noua valoare %d, veche valoare fiind %d.",i,j,k+1,k);    
                        if(dbg)
                            ("\nValoarea returnata este 0, merg cu urmatoarea valoare %d si verific valabilitatea.",k+1);

                        //back(k+1);
                    }
                    while(valid(++k,i,j)==0);
            }
            else
                if(dbg)
                    printf("\nNu este egala cu 0 ci are valoarea %d",st[i][j]);
        }
    }

    if(k>9 || st[3][3]!=0)
        afisare();

    //afisare();
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    freopen("sudoku.in","r",stdin);

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
            scanf("%d",&st[i][j]);

/*  for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            printf("%2d",st[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }*/

    back(1);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

As I said I don't know how to generate all combinations, I only think I should call the function backtracking not the valid ...

Comment: This is a really long unreadable code without any comments in English, can you elaborate on what "went wrong" ? do you have compilation error ? what do you get ?

Comment: Yes I am checking the current filling is valid, and if it's valid I go for the next value and check, but I want to continue after displaying the solution with recursion and do all combinations.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie 9*9*9 is 729 (~ 2^10)... This isn't a very helpful comment. OP is trying to ask about the principle of backtracking, not the efficiency of the algorithm. Indeed, if you had actually implemented and run the solution yourself, you would see that the worst case (a completely empty grid) finishes in seconds, with most of the time devoted to IO.

Comment: I tryed your code and updated for my necesities, however this code doesn't work for 9x9, I change for 3x3 to 9x9 and It doesn't work,I know it should have one/2 more if's for row/collumn check for every number and box check, but I added a debugging line Here: for(k=1;k<=9;k++)
 if(valid(k,i,j))
 and the i doesn't pass for 1, it's remain only on 1

Comment: @asQuirreL and again my calculations were wrong, I was in a hurry, but your are not correct either. Filling an empty greed might be fast not because the algo is good, but because it is not the worst case, on contrary, it is the best one! In the worst case, when you feel a sudoku greed, your algo trys to put 9 numbers in each box(all 9 are valid at his point), out of which 8 fail further testing(you can't feel some box further). This means every box branches 9 times, this means 9^81.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie I'm dubious about empty grid being the best case, because this algorithm is to find *all* solutions, not a particular solution. This means the amount of time it takes should be proportional to some function of the number of nodes in the DFS Tree, and an empty grid has the most number of possible solutions (leaves in the DFS tree) and so must have the most number of nodes also, no?

Comment: @MarianPavel my solution is very particular to the problem that you posed. If you want to find all solutions to a 9x9 sudoku, using backtracking, then I would recommend implementing an [Exact Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) algorithm. I would recommend [Knuth's Dancing Links Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_X).

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, As the problem is specified above, it is equivalent to finding a permutation of the numbers `[1..9]`, so I believe the upper-bound should be `9!` although I have a feeling the algorithm posed actually has a `9^9` complexity, because it doesn't take advantage of certain truths about the data (like, we can process it in such a way as to fill it from top left to bottom right).

Comment: @asQuirreL my bad, it is about a 3x3 greed, I was speaking about a 9x9 one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is mainly to do formatting, and naming things. You have probably managed to confuse yourself by naming the recursive function `back`, and here's why:

Recursive solutions to problems that require you to find all solutions for a given starting condition, are basically doing a **Depth First Search** in the solution space. This means each recursive call is a **forward** movement.

You do not backtrack by calling a method, you backtrack by *not* calling the forward method anymore, to allow the DFS tree (which the recursion is traversing down one path of) to move back up the path it was looking in.

In your case, you are using a global data structure (`st`) to store your sudoku grid though. Which means, when you are going to backtrack, you need to return the state of the grid to how it was before you called the method. In your case, this means setting the position you were checking in to 0 again.

Here's a guide to the solution, and the way I would solve it, (if I were using a global data structure, which by the way, is not very good programming practice. I would recommend using a class to store the grid).

Firstly, some name changes:

- `void afisare()` will be `void printGrid()` in my solution (the implementation will be the same)
- `int valid(int, int, int)` will be `bool isValid(int, int, int)`, and it can be simplified.
- `void back(int)` will be `void fillEmpty()`

  This function will try filling the next empty space with all possible numbers, and for all valid numbers, it will recurse down and call `fillEmpty()` again. If there are no empty numbers left, it will print the grid, because you've found a solution.

So here's the solution to your problem, as I understood it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int grid[3][3];

void
printGrid()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("%d ", grid[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

bool
isValid(int k, int ii, int jj)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            if( (i != ii || j != jj) && grid[i][j] == k)
                return false;
        }

    return true;
}

void 
fillEmpty()
{
    // Find the next empty position.
    int i, j; bool foundEmpty = false;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            if(grid[i][j] == 0) {
                foundEmpty = true;
                break;
            }

        if(foundEmpty) break;
    }

    // If there are no empty positions left
    // we have reached a solution, so we
    // print it and do nothing else.
    if(!foundEmpty)
    {
        printGrid();
        return;
    }

    // Try every number
    for(int k = 1; k <= 9; ++k)
        if( isValid(k, i, j) )
        {
            grid[i][j] = k;
            fillEmpty();
        }

    // Reset the grid position before backtracking.
    grid[i][j] = 0;
}

int 
main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            scanf("%d", &grid[i][j]);

    printGrid();
    fillEmpty();

    return 0;
}
```